# Algorithm to find closest integer values that meet certain criteria

Tags: algorithm, math, formula, equation

*Edited to clarify the application by adding units (ml) and explaining the difficulty to measure wet reagents by units of 1/26. The word 'solution' was ambiguous because it was used to mean both a chemical solution as well as the solution to the problem.*

*Added results based on Edward's reply*

The real world application is that I am trying to determine the closest "convenient" volumes to use when mixing reagents A and B to create a solution (in the wet chemistry sense) that best approximates a specific A:B ratio. Let's define "convenient" as divisible by 5.

Example

Given:

```
1. X = A/(A+B) * C 
2. Y = B/(A+B) * C
3. X + Y = C
4. A, B, C always positive integer

// e.g. a 500ml solution (wet chemistry sense) C with a 1:25 ratio of A and B 
A = 1
B = 25
C = 500
```

This gives the volumes to use of `X` and `Y` to create the solution (wet chemistry sense) with the proper A:B ratio.

```
X =   500/26 = ~19.23ml
Y = 12500/26 = ~480.77ml
C = 13000/26 = 500ml
```

These are the exact volumes create a total volume of 500ml, but trying to measure reagent volumes in units of 1/26ml is a challenge.

How to find "convenient values" (integer divisible by 5) for X, Y, and C that best approximate the exact values of X, Y, and C that would be multiples of 1/26? In this case I found as the closest "convenient" values for X, Y, C:

```
X =  20ml
Y = 500ml
C = 520ml
```

C in this case (520ml) is more than the required volume of 500ml, but it is more practical to physically measure the volumes of 20mL and 500mL than it would be to measure reagent volumes in 1/26ths. The extra 20mL is discarded, the cost for using nice values.

RESULTS BASED ON EDWARD'S ANSWER

```
A=1   B=25    C=500
X=20  Y=500  C2=520 

A=1   B=20    C=500
X=25  Y=500  C2=525 

A=1   B=100   C=500
X=5   Y=500  C2=505 

A=1   B=75    C=500
X=10  Y=750  C2=760 

A=1   B=50    C=900
X=20  Y=1000 C2=1020
```

Comment: Hi HPM! I don't think so, I edited the question to be clearer. A, B, C will always be rational so X, Y will always be rational. But the number 500/26 is an "ugly number" for the practical purpose a hand. I just saw that the solution I found was by changing the denominator from 26 to 25. Maybe an approach would be to "try" various denominators until X, Y, C are all integers divisible by 5 (see my comment to a-z below)?

Comment: If you want X to be a multiple of 5, write X = 5*x and look for an integer x. Then X is guaranteed to be a multiple of 5.

Comment: I see that you have C = 500 in the problem statement but C = 520 in the example output. I don't understand why it's OK to change C. Isn't it one of the specified data? I mean, it's the amount of solution required -- if you change C, you are changing the problem, aren't you?

Comment: Hi Robert. I updated the question to try to clarify this, why C=520 is the desired result. (Sorry if the question is poorly worded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to adjust `C` so that it absorbs the factor `A+B`. Then the ratio of `A` to `B` would be exact, and `X`, `Y`, and `C` would all be integers. Let `D = 5*(A+B)`, `C2 = ceiling(C/((double)D)) * D` (round up so you get enough `C`), `X = C2/(A+B)*A`, `Y = C2/(A+B)*B`. If you want the closest value of `C`, use `C2 = round(C/((double)D))*D` instead.

If you're mixing chemicals, you probably want to round up rather than round to closest so you'll have enough with a little waste left over, which is better than not having enough.

Comment: I implemented this in a few minutes and it's perfect! I will edit the question to show some sample output.

Comment: I just realized that if D divides C already, C2 will be too big. Probably best to use ceiling instead of integer division and add 1. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Updated my question to show results from your answer.

Comment: One more thing I just thought of ... you probably want to replace `A` with `A/gcd(A,B)` and `B` with `B/gcd(A,B)` at the beginning, to keep the size of the numbers as low as possible. (`gcd` is the greatest common divisor.) It's not an issue in your examples because `A=1` in all of them, but if `A=5` and `B=30` you would probably want `A=1` and `B=6` instead.

Comment: I conveniently ignored the case where `B` is a multiple of `A`. You're absolutely right, and I will implement this (and for completeness modify the output above to include an example).

Answer (score 1):

You can phrase this as an optimization problem with an L1 (absolute value) objective function. (This is using a cannon to swat a mosquito, but I did it because I wanted to figure out about the L1 optimization.) I used the program glpsol from the GLPK package (open source). Here is my program:

```
param A, integer, >= 0;
param B, integer, >= 0;
param C, integer, >= 0;
var x, integer, >= 0;
var y, integer, >= 0;
var e1x, >= 0;
var e1y, >= 0;

minimize e1 : e1x + e1y;

subject to

  c1 : (5*x - (C*A)/(A + B)) <= e1x;
  c2 : ((C*A)/(A + B) - 5*x) <= e1x;
  c3 : (5*y - (C*B)/(A + B)) <= e1y;
  c4 : ((C*B)/(A + B) - 5*y) <= e1y;

solve;

printf "x=%g, y=%g, error=%g\n", x, y, e1;

data;

param A := 1;
param B := 25;
param C := 500;
```

Here is the output:

```
$ glpsol --model find_nice_integers.mod 
[... snip ...]
x=4, y=96, error=1.53846
```

Here are some notes about [how to handle absolute values in optimization problems](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/absolute.htm).

Comment: Thanks Robert, I spent some time looking into GLPK and understanding glpsol. All new to me. Fascinating.

Comment: Constrained optimization is a very large and very important topic. I encourage you to spend some time becoming acquainted with it. Unconstrained optimization is hard enough, and constrained is a whole new world.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are given an integer number `C` and the ratio `p:q` between two other integer numbers `A` and `B` (i.e., `A/B = p/q`).

I will interpret your definition of *convenient* as requiring that `X` and `Y` are both multiple of `5` where

```
X = A / (A+B) * C'
Y = B / (A+B) * C'
C' is close to C
```

Replacing `A/B` with `p/q` we get

```
X = p / (p+q) * C'
Y = q / (p+q) * C'
```

Now, in order for `X` and `Y` to be integer both `p * C'` and `q * C'` must both be multiples of `(p+q)`. And since we can assume that `p:q` is irreductible (i.e., `p` and `q` have no multiples in common) this means that `C'` must be divisible by `p+q`. In addition, `C'/(p+q)` must be multiple of `5`. So, `C'` must be a multiple of `5*(p+q)`.

The multiple of `5*(p+q)` that is closest to `C` is:

```
C' := round(C/(5*(p+q)))*5*(p+q)
```

Now we can calculate:

```
X := p/(p+q)*C'
Y := q/(p+q)*C'
```

and they are indeed multiple of `5` because `C'/(p+q)` is.

Let's see how this behaves with your example:

Inputs:

```
p = 1
q = 25
C = 500
```

Then

```
C' := round(500/5(1+25))*5*(1+25) = round(100/26)*5*26 = 4*5*26 = 520
```

Hence

```
X := p/(p+q)*C' = 1/(1+25)*4*5*26 = 1/26*4*5*26 = 4*5 = 20
Y := q/(p+q)*C' = 25/(1+25)*4*5*26 = 25/26*4*5*26 = 25*4*5 = 500.
```

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

Let's first calculate optimal(float) A and B.

It could be Observed that optimal integer solutions are either {floor(A), ceiling(B)} or {ceiling(A), floor(B)}. So we simply try both and chose the answer with less error.

Comment: You're right, but I think I am having a hard time asking the right question. 19 and 481 would be good solution by this observation. I need to add a criteria such as A and B must be divisible by 5. I'm going to edit the question to clarify that integers are not enough.

Comment: The solution is given for the case, where we want A and B to be divisible by 1 (by being integers). Adjusting it for divisibility by 5, we can take `C' = C/5`, solve the problem for `C'` finding optimal `{A',B'}` and reporting `{5*A',5*B'}` as the answer.